# text based browser with javascript support

Tags: centos, oracle

What I want to ask is purely for educational and learning purpose.

I am trying to download and install Oracle 11g R2 on a CentOS 7 system in text mode. The text based browsers I tried are lynx, links, elinks, links2. None of them have JavaScript embedded in them which is required for sign in processes on Oracle Network.

How can I accomplish this task? What other options are available?

Comment: Spending several hours looking for browser with integrated Javascript and not finding it, I asked this question here. I have just started to learn Linux so compiling and coding is a bit difficult and beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this ELinks manual](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manual.html), JavaScript is supported as long as you compile ELinks with SpiderMonkey. SpiderMonkey is Mozilla's JavaScript engine.